# Angular - Display table list based on a list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm new to Angular and trying to display multiple tables based on a list of values. For each rule refNo there has to be a separate rule conditions table displayed one after the other. At the moment all the tables are displaying the same values.

**RuleComponent.html**

```
  <div  *ngFor="let x of automation_rules_list">

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Ticket Field</th>
          <th>Operator</th>
          <th>Expected Value</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr  *ngFor="let o of automation_rules_conditions_list">
          <td>{{o.ticketField}}</td>
          <td>{{o.ticketField}}</td>
          <td>{{o.operator}}</td>
          <td>{{o.expectedValue}}</td>
          <td><span class="pointer text-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
```

**RuleComponent.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.loadAutomationRules();
}


loadAutomationRules() {

  this.ars.getAutomationRules().subscribe(res => {

    this.automation_rules_list = res;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.automation_rules_list.length; i++) {

      this.loadAutomationRuleConditions(res[i]["refNo"]);

    }


  });

}

loadAutomationRuleConditions(ruleRefNo) {

  this.ars.getAutomationConditions(ruleRefNo).subscribe(res => {

    this.automation_rules_conditions_list = res;


  });


}
```

Comment: can you add the structure for both automation_rules_list and automation_rules_conditions_list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `automation_rules_condition` property in each `automation_rule`.
    loadAutomationRules() {

```
  this.ars.getAutomationRules().subscribe(res => {

    this.automation_rules_list = res;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.automation_rules_list.length; i++) {

      this.loadAutomationRuleConditions(res[i]);

    }


  });

}

loadAutomationRuleConditions(rule) {

  this.ars.getAutomationConditions(rule["refNo"]).subscribe(res => {

    rule.automation_rules_condition = res;


  });

}
```

And you should use `x.automation_rules_condition` to display the table.

```
<div  *ngFor="let x of automation_rules_list">

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Ticket Field</th>
          <th>Operator</th>
          <th>Expected Value</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr  *ngFor="let o of x.automation_rules_condition">
          <td>{{o.ticketField}}</td>
          <td>{{o.ticketField}}</td>
          <td>{{o.operator}}</td>
          <td>{{o.expectedValue}}</td>
          <td><span class="pointer text-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the new data to `automation_rules_conditions_list` instead of overwriting

> If my answer is what you want, I have some suggestions for Rxjs

---

**RuleComponent.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.loadAutomationRules();
}


loadAutomationRules() {

  this.ars.getAutomationRules().subscribe(res => {

    this.automation_rules_list = res;

   // reset automation_rules_conditions_list
   this.automation_rules_conditions_list = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.automation_rules_list.length; i++) {

      this.loadAutomationRuleConditions(res[i]["refNo"]);

    }


  });

}

loadAutomationRuleConditions(ruleRefNo) {

  this.ars.getAutomationConditions(ruleRefNo).subscribe(res => {

    // add the new data to automation_rules_conditions_list
    this.automation_rules_conditions_list.push(res);


  });


}
```